# how to upload file from a link? [PHP]

Tags: php, file-upload, server

I have a php project and it needs to upload a file to the server from a [blob] link... I have searched and all I found was to upload a file with  tag and it is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple file_put_content and file_put_contents
for example

```
file_put_contents("file.extension", ("link"));
```